# Inner join + set max date + naming in ACCESS SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am migrating a query from tables held in MS SQL Server to MS Access 2016. I can't seem to figure out how to use the very common max_date inner join from my SQL query and import to my Access query.

I have searched the site and seen many explanations for how to do it in SQL, and my query in SQL works just fine. My Access query will not work.

```
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[RFIDTAGID], max(dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[TRANSCATION_DATE]) as [max_trxn_date]
    FROM dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
    GROUP BY dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[RFIDTAGID]) as b
ON dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[RFIDTAGID] = b.[RFIDTAGID] AND (dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[TRANSCATION_DATE] = b.[max_trxn_date]))
```

I expect my `[TRANSCATION_DATE]` to only hold the `[max_trxn_date]` so only one max date record is pulled for each `[RFIDTAGID]`. Without naming the join "as b" I don't know how to make this work. Access doesn't seem to take the naming structure I'm used to in SQL. I am getting a compile error for syntax.

Full code below

```
SELECT dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.PROD_ORDER, dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.PART_NUMBER, dbo_LTS_PACKAGE.QUANTITY, dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.LOCATION, dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.TRANSCATION_DATE, dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.CONTAINER_RFIDTAGID, dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.RFIDTAGID, dbo_LTS_DISCRETE_JOB_SUMMARY.MFG_DELIVERY_DATE, dbo_LTS_DISCRETE_JOB_SUMMARY.EXTENSION_DATE, dbo_LTS_DISCRETE_JOB_SUMMARY.STATUS, dbo_LTS_DISCRETE_JOB_SUMMARY.PBG, dbo_LTS_LOCATION.TYPE

FROM (dbo_LTS_LOCATION 

INNER JOIN (dbo_LTS_DISCRETE_JOB_SUMMARY 
INNER JOIN dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY 
ON (dbo_LTS_DISCRETE_JOB_SUMMARY.[PROD_ORDER] = dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[PROD_ORDER]) 

AND (dbo_LTS_DISCRETE_JOB_SUMMARY.[DISCRETE_JOB_NUMBER] = dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[JOB_NUMBER])) 
ON dbo_LTS_LOCATION.[DESIGNATION] = dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[LOCATION]) 

INNER JOIN dbo_LTS_PACKAGE ON dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[RFIDTAGID] = dbo_LTS_PACKAGE.[RFIDTAGID]

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[RFIDTAGID], max(dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[TRANSCATION_DATE]) as [max_trxn_date]
    FROM dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY
    GROUP BY dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[RFIDTAGID]) as b
ON dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[RFIDTAGID] = b.[RFIDTAGID] AND (dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.[TRANSCATION_DATE] = b.[max_trxn_date]))

WHERE (((dbo_LTS_TRANSACTION_HISTORY.PROD_ORDER)="123456"));
```

Comment: AFAIK, this JOIN should work. Edit question to show sample data (as text, not image). Show the complete query SQL. What you posted shows extra ). Do you know you created field name with misspelled word "TRANSCATION"?

Comment: @June7 yes, unfortunately it was misspelled in the master tables in SQL and I cannot change them.

Comment: Looks okay. Did you use Access query builder to construct that SQL? I would build the inner query first and save it with name "b". Then build the outer query with reference to the first object. If that runs then try copy/paste the first query SQL statement into the second. "Will not work" means what - error message, wrong results, nothing happens?

Comment: I used Access query builder to construct some of it. The part I'm having trouble with I do not see options for. "Will not work" means that is shows a syntax error, as I mentioned.

Comment: Should post the complete error message. What is the part that causes trouble? I can't tell from the info provided. I have done joins that involve aggregate query so I am at a loss. If you build the queries separately as described, do they work? Test the outer query without the aggregate table join.